# Getting a downvote everyday from the same user

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

I am aware of the rule that the same user can't downvote another user many times the same day, otherwise it's considered a "serial downvoter" and the negative votes get deleted.
Now I checked my account, since I'm in holiday from a week I'm not answering to questions, I'm just reading questions. And I get downvoted everyday from old answers, answers that seem correct to me, without any comment left.

Is it possible to see from who I get these downvotes?

Comment: I know us common-folk can't see who voted...but i'm pretty sure it's possible for the wise-men/oracles to use their super-powers to investigate.... *if need be*.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't really know what to attribute this to, but while you *have* been getting a few down-votes recently, they're not coming from the same user(s) and there doesn't appear to be any connection between the voters apart from their involvement in [ios](/questions/tagged/ios) - which, of course, is to be expected considering *your* involvement in that tag. Occam's razor sez they're probably just encountering your answers naturally and finding them lacking in some way.

So I don't really have anything to offer, except... Well, when you see a down-vote, give the answer a once-over and see if there's anything you can do to improve it. If not, just shrug it off and move on.

Comment: I've found this to be indicative of a link to an answer ending up on another site (context: "I tried what this answer said"). People find it and then go through the user's history. Fix the one that gets dinged the most and you take away the trampoline.

Comment: is serial-upvoting a problem on SO?

Comment: It can be, @iight. See: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/vote-fraud-and-you/

Comment: very interesting article...that would be a cool statistic to show on the user screen, a `sportsmanlike conduct` rating. I've been starting to mess around with data.stackoverflow and wanted to make this query but realized we can't see voting details. Good to know it's on the radar! (hope i'm not <sub>too</sub> guilty)

Comment: You're not. Generally, it's something you gotta really *work* at - like, going down the list of someone's posts voting on every one, or using sockpuppets.